# Reverse DNS on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-dns

I'm developing a restful API as a fun challenge. For that, I've got a server running on AWS and also a custom domain registered as I would like to use it as the address for my API calls.

I've been following this guide on youtube to use my custom domain name on my API: https://youtu.be/LUFn-QVcmB8?t=927
By 15:27 he mentions the need to set up a reverse DNS on the server, but I can't find that option on AWS ec2.

RDNS on ec2 doesn't seem to be as straightforward as in the video, and I couldn't guide myself through the explanations I've found as I don't have any knowledge of networking configuration. Does anyone know the steps I need to follow to configure rDNS on my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't configure reverse DNS on an instance, but for an IP address. You must have given your instance a persistent Elastic IP address, and then you can [request Amazon to set reverse DNS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts?#/rdns-limits) for that IP address.

Comment: Your answer is simple, but it did make some concepts clear in my mind.